# CloudModule is not working in ionic 3

Tags: cloud, ionic3

I am using ionic 3 for my app. Every thing working fine until I added cloud-angular & used CloudModule.forRoot(cloudSettings) code. After running ionic run android --device I get blank screen with Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "ionic-native" in console. My package.json file:

```
{
"name": "ionic-hello-world",
"author": "Ionic Framework",
"homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
"clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
"build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
"ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
"ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
},
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "4.0.0",
"@angular/common": "4.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "4.0.0",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "4.0.0",
"@angular/core": "4.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "4.0.0",
"@angular/http": "4.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "4.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.0.0",
"@angular/platform-server": "4.0.0",
"@ionic-native/call-number": "3.8.0",
"@ionic-native/core": "^3.10.3",
"@ionic-native/device": "3.8.0",
"@ionic-native/facebook": "^3.10.3",
"@ionic-native/geolocation": "3.8.0",
"@ionic-native/google-plus": "^3.10.3",
"@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^3.8.0",
"@ionic-native/social-sharing": "3.8.0",
"@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^3.9.2",
"@ionic-native/status-bar": "^3.10.3",
"@ionic/cloud-angular": "^0.12.0",
"@ionic/storage": "^2.0.1",
"font-awesome": "4.7.0",
"ionic-angular": "3.0.1",
"ionicons": "3.0.0",
"jssha": "2.2.0",
"rxjs": "5.1.1",
"sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
"zone.js": "^0.8.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@ionic/app-scripts": "1.3.0",
"@types/jssha": "0.0.29",
"@types/node": "7.0.13",
"typescript": "~2.2.1"
},
"cordovaPlugins": [
"cordova-plugin-whitelist",
"cordova-plugin-console",
"cordova-plugin-statusbar",
"cordova-plugin-device",
"cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
"ionic-plugin-keyboard"
],
"description": "App desc"
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-
angular';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { LoginPage } from '../pages/login/login';
import { GooglePlus } from '@ionic-native/google-plus';
import { Facebook } from '@ionic-native/facebook';
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';
import { SocialSharing } from '@ionic-native/social-sharing';
import { PeopleService } from '../providers/people-service';
import { Device } from '@ionic-native/device';
import { CallNumber } from '@ionic-native/call-number';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-
browser/animations';
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser';
import { Helpmenu } from '../pages/helpmenu/helpmenu';
import { CloudSettings, CloudModule } from '@ionic/cloud-angular';

const cloudSettings: CloudSettings = {
'core': {
'app_id': 'e5343a76'
}
};

@NgModule({
declarations: [
MyApp,
HomePage,
LoginPage,
],
imports: [
BrowserModule,
BrowserAnimationsModule,
HttpModule,
IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
CloudModule.forRoot(cloudSettings),
IonicStorageModule.forRoot()
],
bootstrap: [IonicApp],
entryComponents: [
MyApp,
HomePage,
LoginPage,
],
providers: [SocialSharing, Geolocation, {provide: ErrorHandler, 
useClass: IonicErrorHandler}, PeopleService, StatusBar, Device, 
CallNumber, SplashScreen, Facebook, InAppBrowser, GooglePlus]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: can you [edit] your question and add app.module.ts?

Comment: @suraj app.module.ts added.

Comment: hmm.. try updating `@ionic/cloud-angular`..

Comment: this is latest version.

Comment: `npm install @ionic/cloud-angular@latest --save`

Comment: bawa it works. thanks.

Comment: great ! added as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to update your cloud angular package.

Do:

```
npm install @ionic/cloud-angular@latest --save
```